# How to save figure using .pyscript?

Tags: pyscript

The below code shows what i have tried.It works fine in the jupyter notebook but shows blank when i try in pyscript.

```
<py-config>
        "packages" = ["pandas","Jinja2","openpyxl","opencv-python"]
        [files]
        "n2.png" = "n2.png"
</py-config>
<script type="py">
      import cv2
      from pyscript import display
      img = cv2.imread("n2.png")
      h, w, channels = img.shape
      image1 = img[:60, :1000]
      cv2.imwrite('image1.jpg',image1)
</script>
```

Comment: Don't ['how to save figure using pyscript'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72463208/8508004) and ['Why wont py script write file?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74828932/8508004) address your title? I cannot imagine it would work as you 
 post it in  Jupyter wrapped with those `display()` functions.

Comment: OpenCV is for figure.  @Jupyter only the python code.  **display()** was to show that it displays the image and need to figure out a way to save it to my **@py-script** project.

Comment: "Access to fetch at 'file:...n2.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted."  when trying this script in Chrome, this message is show under  Inspect/Console

Comment: Did you upload n2.png?you need to upload it to pyscript environment.